# Проектировка таблиц Mysql

Tags: mysql

Как правильно спроектировать 2 таблицы в моем случае? При регистрации нового юзера получается создается организация,в свою очередь в данной организации можно создать еще юзеров,то есть работников.Пока я решил создать 2 таблицы отдельно таблицу организации и юзеры которые будут иметь `id` организции.Задача в том что надо различать кто создатель данной организации,как быть в данной ситуации? Хранить в таблице организации `Id` создателя или в юзерах поле `founder` а так же `org_id`  в которой он состоит?

```
Organizations
--------------
id
name

Users
--------------
id
org_id
```

Comment: Ну как то многовато табли для одной организации мне кажется.Если добавить в таблице юзеров поле founder и хранить там id юзера?

Comment: А юзер может быть только в одной организации?

Comment: Создателя надо хранить в таблице Organizations.

Comment: Да только в одной

Answer (score 2):

Идеологически правильно хранить id создателя в самой организации. Это конечно несколько усложняет процедуру создания организации. Но это гарантирует, что у одной организации будет только один создатель. И ни каких ошибках нельзя будет сделать второго создателя.

При такой структуре так же быстрее будет поиск создателя данной организации, т.к. нужный user будет браться сразу по id, а не перебором всех пользователей по org_id.

Comment: То есть сперва я добавляю юзера, далее добавляю организаю и присваиваю полю created_by id последнего запроса,и потом в таблице юзеров обновляю поле org_id  и вношу id созданной организации я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Либо так, либо наоборот, сначала организацию, потом добавляем юзера и апдейтим created_by. В принципе в любом направлении. Но что бы это проделать в одной из таблиц created_by или org_id должны позволять NULL значения. Надо решить где это более допустимо. Я бы скорее пошел на NULL в организации и возможно создавал бы юзера в триггере на создание организации, особенно если создание организации может происходить из нескольких местах внешних программ

Comment: Null  я разрешаю в users.org_id так как юзер может быть зарегистрирован как простое физ. лицо,а это уже не организация!

Comment: @quaresma89 Тогда по вашему варианту лучше, что бы NULL не плодить. Надеюсь "создатель" организации чисто номинальное, не юридическое понятие, потому как учредителями организации может быть одно и более физ лиц, а так же друге организации

Comment: @quaresma89 И опять же у вас тогда пользователь может сначала зарегатся как физик, а позже захотеть создать организацию и интерфесно и в базе это будет в одном порядке происходить.  P.S. Если бы у вас был Oracle, я бы возможно предложил брать id для организаций и юзеров из одного источника и id создателя просто делать равным id организации. А вы подумайте, кстати, очень часто у физлиц и организаций очень много общего и приходится делать таблицу, содержащую и тех и других ...

Comment: Ну без Null тут не обойтись,так как я ставлю ограничение внешнего ключа на org_id, без этого я не смогу получается создавать юзера не имеющего организацию!

Comment: @quaresma89 ну да, под "не плодить" я имел ввиду что нет смысла позволять null в обоих таблицах, а раз в user null обязан быть, то значит в организациях created_by делать not null и обеспечить этим невозможность существования организации без создателя (если вам конечно такое явно для чего то не нужно)

Comment: Все верно,так и есть!